# Android backward compatibility issue with styles

Tags: android, android-styles, android-compatibility

In my **styles.xml** inside the values directory I defined my custom button as follows:

```
<style name="Button" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

It is working at least with my Android 4.2 device but Android 2.3 does not respect the `minHeight` value. I have also problems with fonts, in my `TextView`s Android 2.3 seems to use enormous fonts instead of the default values from the style I inherit in the following code:

```
<style name="TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>
```

Is there any special thing I must do for API < 11?

Thank you so much,

Comment: Have you tried setting the parent to Widget.TextView instead of Widget.Holo.Light.TextView?

Answer (score 0):

For using the holo theme in android 2.3, you shall use the androids compatibility library.
For holo theme you shall use the andorid support library v7.

Check the following link for more details:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: In that website does not appear the word 'holo'. In addition, this is not the way to use the Holo Theme in Android earlier versions.

Comment: He means tha appcompat lib: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html - but this is for having actionbar and some holo styles in android 2.1+ but does not enable earlier version newer style elements

Comment: Anyway, that's not the question.